# When I blit surface, special tag BLEND_RGB_ADD doesn't works for me

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```
def draw_circle(surf, col, center, radius, alpha=255, add=False):
    new_surf = pygame.Surface((radius * 2, radius * 2))
    pygame.draw.circle(new_surf, col, (radius, radius), radius)
    new_surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    new_surf.set_alpha(alpha)
    if add == False:
        surf.blit(new_surf, (center[0]-radius, center[1]-radius))
    else:
        surf.blit(new_surf, (center[0]-radius, center[1]-radius), special_flags=BLEND_RGB_ADD)
```

somewhere else in my code:¨

```
draw_circle(self.surf, (20, 20, 20), self.pos, self.height * 2, add=True)
```

and I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'BLEND_RGB_ADD' is not defined
```

Comment: You are going to need to import it or prefix it with `pygame.`

Comment: Have you tried `pygeame.BLEND_RGB_ADD`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@Rabbid76 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771411/when-i-blit-surface-special-tag-blend-rgb-add-doesnt-works-for-me/68773844#comment121540517_68771411), the following works:

```
special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGB_ADD
```